# Why is the $\tan$ function differentiable even though it is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, trigonometry, continuity

If only continuous functions can be differentiable, then how can the tangent function $\tan$ be differentiated, even though $\tan$ is not a continuous function?

Comment: $\tan x$ is not differentiable on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $\tan$ is continuous. All elementary functions are continuous everywhere.

Comment: @Ruben, $\tan$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$.  "$\tan$ is not differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$" is a bit like saying that the square root function is not differentiable on $\mathbb{Z}[X, Y]$.

Comment: @alexey It's more like the square root function is not differentiable on $\Bbb R$, which is true.

Comment: @Ruben, ok, let's agree on a compromise: it is like the square root function is not differentiable on $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. :) (Note that $[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$.)  Though, here $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ is not a manifold of the same dimension as $[0,\infty)$, so, let's better talk about continuity: the square root function is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$.

Comment: @Alexey Ok sure, of course the statement is kind of silly. I was just trying to stimulate the person asking the question into thinking carefully about the domain of the function and its points of discontinuity.

Comment: @Riya, incidentally, it is important to note the difference between the notion of *continuity* of a function and the notion of *connectedness* of its domain.  Virtually all functions that normal people encounter in their lives are continuous, but many of them do not have connected domain (see $\tan$, for example).  The domain of a function of a complex variable can also be connected but not *simply connected*, etc.  IMO, the emphasis on *continuity* in calculus courses is not well justified -- the connectedness of domains is less obvious to verify.

Answer (score 7):

The tangent function **is** continuous. I suppose that you are confused by the fact that it has singularities at $k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, but these points are simply not in the domain of the function.

To be more precise: The function

$$ \tan\colon \Bbb R \setminus \{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}: k\in\Bbb Z\} \to \Bbb R$$

is continuous and indeed even differentiable.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, $\tan$ **is** a continuous (and differentiable) function. Keep in mind that its domain is $\mathbb R\setminus\left\{\frac\pi2+k\pi\,\middle|\,k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$. Since it is the quotient of two differentiable functions, it is differentiable.